# Understanding go tool compile and link commands

Tags: go, compiler-construction

I understand that there are three steps involved in converting a high level language code to machine language or executable code namely - compiling, assembling, and linking.

As per go docs **go tool compile** does the following - 
`It then writes a single object file named for the basename of the first source file with a .o suffix`

So, the final object file must contain the machine language code (after compiling and assembling are run) of each file. If I pass **go tool compile -S** on the go file, it shows assembly language go generates.

After this when I run **go tool link** on the object file, it must link all required object files (if multiple) and then generate final machine language code (based on GOOS and GOARCH). It generates a file **a.out**

Have few basic questions here -

How do I know which variables and when are they going to be allocated memory in stack and heap? Does it matter if I generate executable for one machine and run on another with different architecture?

**My test program**

```
package main

func f(a *int, b *int) *int { 

    var c = (*a + *b); 
    var d = c;
    return &d;
}

func main() {
    var a = 2;
    var b = 6;

    f(&a,&b);
}
```

Result of **go tool compile -m -l test.go**

```
test.go:6: moved to heap: d
test.go:7: &d escapes to heap
test.go:3: f a does not escape
test.go:3: f b does not escape
test.go:14: main &a does not escape
test.go:14: main &b does not escape
```

Comment: You can see exactly what the Go tool does with the `-x` flag. Memory allocation is at runtime of course. You can see what is stack vs heap by printing the escape analysis output .

Comment: By memory allocation I meant the indication that a certain variable is going to be assigned heap memory or stack memory. Where do I see that?

Comment: Oh, it's in the compiler optimization output; `-m`

Comment: Thanks @JimB I did that and pasted the result above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In which step is the memory getting allocated?

It depends, some during linking, some during compiling, most during runtime (And some during loading).

> How do I know which variables and when are they going to be allocated memory in stack and heap?

Ad hoc you do not know at all. The compiler decides this. If the compiler can prove that a variable does not escape it might keep it on the stack. Google for "golang escape analysis". There is a flag -m which makes the compiler output his decisions if you are interested in it.

> Does it matter if I generate executable for one machine and run on another with different architecture?

No, but simply because this does not work at all: Executables are tied to architecture and won't run on a different one.

It seems you are mixing up compilation/linking and memory allocation. The later is pretty different from the former two. (Technically your linked program may contain memory and during loading it might get even more, but this is highly technical and architecture specific and really nothing to be concerned of).

Comment: I did compile with -m option. As per the output if a variable escapes a function it is allocated on heap and if it does not escape then on stack. It doesn't say anything about the temp variable c though. Edited my question with program and compile output.

Comment: "Executables are tied to architecture and won't run on a different one" - broadly accurate but there is some compatibility; e.g., windows-386 (32bit) should run on windows-amd64 (64bit).

Comment: @Sam Most probably the compiler simply optimises away most code of f. Just because you write `var c ...` does not mean that there will actual memory from RAM be used as such stuff can be done e.g. in registers.